# id type in mongoengine objects

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I use mongoengine and when I call a class mongoengine give me  error 
for example when I use : `Site.objects()`
I get this
`TypeError: id must be an instance of (str, unicode, ObjectId), not <type 'dict'>`

and it's my class definition :

```
class Site(db.Document):
    siteURL = db.URLField('''required = True''')
    name = db.StringField(required = True)
    pages = db.ListField(ReferenceField(Page))
    siteId = db.IntField(required = True , unique = True )
    views = db.IntField(required = True , default = 0)
    visitors = db.IntField(required = True , default = 0)
    stat_by_hour = LimitedListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(HourStat))
    weekday_stat = db.ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(WeekdayStat)) 
    os = db.ListField(ReferenceField(OS))
    countries = db.ListField(ReferenceField(Country))
    cities = db.ListField(ReferenceField(City))
    browsers = db.ListField(ReferenceField(Browser))
    resolutions = db.ListField(ReferenceField(Resolution))
    mostVisitedDays = db.SortedListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(MostVisitedDay) ,  ordering="visitors")
```

Comment: Could you give more context around the error, like editing the question to include more code? It looks like you try to insert a `Site` but you are providing an `_id` that's not one of the basic types allowed by mongoengine.

Comment: If you have the error while querying (I.e calling Site.objects(), it means that what you have in the database has something weird has _id), maybe your existing document don’t match this schéma?